# jQuery tools: tooltip makes title disappear?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm trying to make tooltips appear using jQuery Tools' tooltip feature. When the mark up looks like this, it's fine:

```
<input type="submit" title="Submit your foo" value="foo"></input>
```

But when the input is disabled, the title mysteriously disappears from the DOM:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" title="Sorry, you cannot submit your foo" value="foo"></input>
```

This only happens when I try to use jQuery tools. If I don't use jQuery tools, the title appears just fine (default browser effect). Any ideas what's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7jCXz/ - this example seems to remove the title attribute in both input tags, not just the disabled one.

Comment: Can you show us a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or similar, demo to see what you're doing?

Comment: OK. Trying to put together a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) your submit button into an `div`, then use tooltip on your `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[disabled="disabled"]').each(function(){
        var $tit = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).wrap('<div class="submitWrapper" title="' + $tit + '"></div>');
    });
    //$('.submitWrapper').tooltip(); // or something like this
    $('.submitWrapper').on('mouseover', function(){
        alert('submitWrapper clicked!');
    });
});
```

---

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tnEmZ/)

Comment: Why? I have title attributes in so many links, submits, etc. -- where I think they should go (semantically speaking). I try to avoid bloating mark up by adding divs, spans, etc. if I can. What's causing my problem?

Comment: Probably the tooltip does not work with disabled elements. So I think you should wrap them in to `div`'s (only disabled elements). BTW, could you tell me which tooltip are you using?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCXz/1/) works in Opera. Could you test it and tell me what your browser is?

Comment: Problem exist in Chrome and FF. Problem also exist in your example. The "No" button does not have a tool tip. That's the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: Isn't this too complex of a solution?

Comment: Also, [this article](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2010/4/23/Attaching-mouse-events-to-a-disabled-input-element) has a great solution.

Comment: Disabled elements don't fire events in many browsers. I don't think there would be simpler solution to tackle this issue :(

Comment: OK, I thought it was a problem with jQuery Tools. Since it's the browser that is not firing the events, the problem now make sense to me. How do I select all input tags that are type=submit and not disabled=disabled?

Comment: Use this selector: `$('input[type="submit"]')` or `$(':submit')`

Comment: `$(':submit:not(:disabled)')` for those not disabled

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to help you, but hopefully helps someone else.

Using jQuery Tooltip, if you want to get/set the title attribute after the tooltip has been initialised, you need to use

```
$(foo).tooltip("option","content")
```

or

```
$(foo).tooltip("option","content","some new content")
```

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content